# Floor Arrangement

Tags: logical-deduction

> Ten people G, H, I, J, K, L, W, X, Y and Z live in a building  with
>   four floors.
>
> Each floor has 3 flats: flat 1, flat 2, and  flat 3, in the  same  order  from  left  to  right.
>
> Ground floor is numbered floor 1 and topmost floor is floor 4.
>
> Each flat is built in such a way that Flat 1 of floor 2 is just above Flat 1
>   of floor 1 and so on.
>
> The two flats in which no one lives are on even numbered floors and in even  numbered flats.
>
> G does not live on an even-numbered floor and even-numbered flat.
>
> W  lives in the flat just above H.
>
> The flat between K and X is vacant and K lives in one of the flat above X.
>
> L lives in an odd-numbered flat which is in the left of X.
>
> Z and Y live on the same floor and no one else is living with them on that floor.
>
> G lives on a floor and flat just above W’s floor and flat.
>
> I lives on one of the floors on which one flat is vacant.
>
> Z and I both live in a flat which is numbered 1.

**I have tried:**

I got confusion in solving this floor puzzle

Total 10 People - G,H,I ,J,K,L,W,X,Y,Z - SO each floor has three flats - so total - 4*3 = 12 flats

**Please guide me for solving this puzzle**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arrangement is:

> ```
>                   1   2   3
>
>             4     Z   -   Y
>             3     J   K   G
>             2     I   -   W
>             1     L   X   H
> ```

First, let's number the statements for easy reference:

(1) The two flats in which no one lives are on even numbered floor and in even numbered flat.
(2) G does not live on even numbered floor and even numbered flat.
(3) W lives in the flat just above H.
(4) The flat between K and X is vacant and K lives in one of the flat above X.
(5) L lives in an odd numbered flat which is in the left of X.
(6) Z and Y lives on the same floor and no one else is living with them on that floor.
(7) G lives on a floor and flat just above W's floor and flat.
(8) I live on one of the floor on which one flat is vacant.
(9) Z and I both live in the flat which is numbered 1.

Now you can start filling in the tenants:

Statement (1) tells you that the empty flats must be 2.2. and 4.2. Statement (4) means that K and X live in 3.2 and 1.2. Statement (5) puts L in 1.1.

Statements (3) and (7) tell you that G lives directly over W and W lives directly over H. Statement (9) says that Z and I live in flat 1, so G, W and H must live in flat 3.

Statements (6) says that Z and Y live on a floor with a vacant flat. Z lives in flat 1 (9), so Y must live in flat 3. This can only be the top floor, because otherwise G, W and H can't live directly above each other. This puts G, W and H in flats 3.3, 2.3 and 2.3.

Statement (2) puts I in flat 2.1. The remaining tenant, J, about whom we don't know anything, gets flat 3.1.

Statement (2) hasn't been used yet, but you can use it to check the solution: G lives in 3.3.

Comment: Great @M Oehm i have to review your answer,Thanks a Lot

Comment: You should probably review it before you accept it as correct.

Comment: @M Oehm how statement 2 puts   I in 2.1 can you please explain

Comment: @Learninguser: Oops, that should be statement (8), which should make it clear why - the only free apartments are 2.1 and 3.1. The next paragraph says that stetement (2) hasn't been used yet, so that was clearly a typo.

Comment: @M Oehm i posted wrongly one puzzle here if possible please answer - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2204739/rectangular-arrangement

Comment: These puzzles are really not hard to solve and it's not a lot of fun to have others solve them. Why not try it yourself?

Answer (score -1):

I SOLVED IT.

> f1  f2  f3
> 4 Z   -   Y3 J   K   G
> 2 I   -   W
> 1 L   X   H

Comment: Congratulations! That being said, there is [another answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50281/floor-arrangement/50282#50282) that was submitted and accepted as correct already which is the same as yours. Please look at the answer linked and note how it is formatted. It hides the answer portion with ">!" tags ([spoiler notation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers)) and clearly explains the logic and steps involved in solving. You should visit [the help center](/help) and take [the tour](/tour). Good luck and happy puzzling!